# Docker volume and mount

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm not very clear about the behavior of volume and mount

**1. no volume, no mount**

```
 FROM centos
 RUN mkdir /data
 CMD ["bash"]

 docker build -t vm .
 docker run --rm vm mkdir /data/new
```

I'm sure /data/new will not exist in host disk

**2. no volume, with mount**

```
 FROM centos
 RUN mkdir /data
 CMD ["bash"]

 docker build -t vm .
 docker run --rm -v /tmp:/data vm mkdir /data/new
```

/tmp/new exists after container delete without VOLUME, what is the point of VOLUME?

**3. with volume, no mount**

```
 FROM centos
 RUN mkdir /data
 VOULME /data
 CMD ["bash"]

 docker build -t vm .
 docker run --rm  vm mkdir /data/new
```

Will dir `new` exist in host disk?

**4. with volume, with mount**

```
 FROM centos
 RUN mkdir /data
 VOULME /data
 CMD ["bash"]

 docker build -t vm .
 docker run --rm -v /tmp:/data vm mkdir /data/new
```

Dir `new` will exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `VOLUME` in dockerfile only supports docker-managed volumes
2. `docker run --volume` supports both docker-managed volumes and host path volumes
3. `docker run --volume` **overrides** dockerfile

There is more explanation on [official docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/).

Also [a helpful post here](http://container42.com/2014/11/03/docker-indepth-volumes/)

Comment: official docs pages changed. Can you please help to locate where it is written that "docker run --volume overrides dockerfile"?