# How to mount a host volume from dockerfile

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile

I was trying to mount host volume(windows 10) from dockerfile. I was using the command:

`docker run -v <host-dir>:<container-dir> <image-name>`

from docker terminal. It was working fine from docker terminal. But when I tried to do the same from dockerfile execution it's getting stopped because of this command. Please help how to mount host volume from dockerfile.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume

Comment: command which i was using is: docker run -v /<host-dir>:<container-dir> image-name

Comment: And your Dockefile and `docker build` command?

Comment: The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26053710) seems to be that it is not possible to do this from `Dockerfile` , but see that page for other options. The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) shows how to do it with `docker-compose` but I've not seen mention of how to achieve the same with `Dockerfile`, which is meant for building images.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly have you written in your Dockerfile?

For Dockerfiles there exists a VOLUME instruction, which can probably help you.

I recommend reading the following 2 links for clarification on Docker volumes:

[Official Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/)

[Helpful blogpost](http://container-solutions.com/understanding-volumes-docker/)

Edit: I may have found another post which could help you immensely: [Docker volume and mount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293084/docker-volume-and-mount)

Comment: i was trying to run this command from dockerfile: 
 
RUN  -v /c/users/rajesh:/var/test imagename

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work, as the RUN-Instruction in the Dockerfile isn't the same as the command "docker run". The RUN-Instruction acts as if you were typing your commands on a shell, while the "docker run"-command starts up a new container.

I highly recommend you reading the official guide on how to write Dockerfiles (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

PS: Sorry for spamming you with links, I think the current one will help you the fastest

Comment: is there a way to mount host dir from dockerfile?

Comment: If you use "VOLUME /data" for example, it will mount the /data directory inside the container to "/var/lib/docker/volumes/[random hash]/_data/" on your docker-host. So it is mounted on the host. You can't mount to a specific directory though, as every host can be different and the image might not work on other hosts (since the mounted directory could not exist).